# How to check a value of a listbox in visual studio 2015

Tags: wpf, visual-studio

I am using visual basic.

I have a list box full of around 10-12 values. I was curious how I would check the selected value.

All i'm trying to do is change an image source depending on the selected value in the listbox.

Below is the code I have so far:

```
    ' For Each item As ListItem In lstBox.Items 
      If item.Value = "My Value" 
      lblNumber.Content = "$123"
      End If  
      Next
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you could use the following code:

```
Private Sub Button_Click()
If ListBox.ListIndex <> -1 Then MsgBox ListBox.Value
End Sub
```

Please let me know if I do not understand, however.

**EDIT:** Is the below what you are asking for? This code should display the selected value within the listbox.

```
Dim I As Long
Dim msg As String

    If ListBox1.ListIndex <> -1 Then
        For I = 0 To ListBox1.ColumnCount - 1
            msg = msg & ListBox1.Column(I) & vbCrLf
        Next I
    End If

    MsgBox msg
```

Comment: I tried that code but it didn't work. Value isn't apart of ListBox apparently.

What i'm trying to do is give the user a choice of a list box. So on my screen I have an image and a listbox. What I want is when the user selects an item from the list, I want it to update the picture.

Comment: My apologies. Do you have any code in which you have tried? It is very difficult to make an assumption on what one is asking when given no example of what they have tried.

I also assume that you are programming in VBA?

Comment: Sorry, I am new to coding in general. Is there a difference between Visual Studio and VBA? I'm using the program 'Visual Studio 2015 Express' From there my project is being coded in visual basic using WPF's if that helps. I'm using .NET Framework 4.5.2.

Comment: Visual Studio is the IDE you are running from. Your project is coded in VBA. If you are using WPF, does that include XAML?

Comment: Ahh, sorry then. I can't really help you much further as I didn't realise it was touching XAML. However, if you show other users what you've tried, you're more likely to receive a better answer.

Comment: Should I create a new question? Or should I wait for another response? I'm new to stackoverflow, my apologies.

Comment: I would advise re-creating your question with as much information as possible. As I said earlier, you'll find that the developers on here will find it difficult to decipher what you are actually asking for if you provide so little information.

I would suggest providing your sample XAML and VBA code (if that is what you're programming in) and letting others know just what it is you're looking to achieve.

I haven't touched XAML unfortunately and have only used Visual Studio for C# winforms so I can't be of much more help down the WPF route, I'm sorry.